# How to use DAQmx Timing (Sample Clock ) in C#.Net

Tags: c#, labview, nidaqmx, measurement-studio

I'm using Measurement Studio. I need to use the `DAQmx Timing VI` functionality in my C# application. How to do this. Please Help me.

The VIs are here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, general procedure from LabVIEW is to:

1. create a task (You are not displaying this VI).
2. modify timings for the task.
3. start the task.
4. take measurements.
5. stop the task.

You may have avoided making the tasks before if you only needed basic timing functionality, but if you need to use more advanced timings you need to use the DAQmx Timing VI.

I haven't used Measurement Studio but I hope this helps.

Comment: connect the probe first. click on measurement -studio icon and u can set samples . then drag and drop the daq mx. add timings using timer or clock then take reading .

Answer (score 1):

i think connect the probe first. click on measurement -studio icon and u can set samples.set how many samples per minute . then drag and drop the daq mx. add timings using timer or clock then take reading